# Get an object's start and end position in world space

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a **plane** whose scale is set to 1,1,1. I am willing to get its **start position** and **end position**. That what is the position at start of the object in world space and what is the end position.
One easy way to do this job is to place object in start and end of the plane and get object positions but i want to do it through the floor **Only**.

I just tried this code but its not bringin position in world space.

```
Debug.Log(floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.min);
        Debug.Log(floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.max);
        Debug.Log(floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.center);
        Debug.Log(floor.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.extents);
```

Comment: Your code seems to be OK. What do think is wrong? What happens when you temporarily create a new cube object at `bounds.min` and `bounds.max` Note that the transform of an object might be different from the center

Comment: What do you mean by end and start of a plane? A plane has 4 sides, can't you just use, floor.position and add or substract half of the floors scale in the direction you are considering start or end?

Comment: Do you do any manipulation with the mesh itself? If so try calling recalculate bounds before printing out bounds to the console. Also what results are you getting. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.RecalculateBounds.html

Answer (score 2):

Renderer.bounds will only match size of the plane if plane transform is aligned with the world. In other world it will only work if there isn't any rotation.

Another approach to get corners of the plane would be to look into the mesh vertices directly. This would require finding vertices on the corners first. Forget that.

1. Create 2 new game objects and place them on the corners of your plane
2. Parent two corner objects to plane object

**[image: Hierarchy]**

Each corners transform.position will now give you world space position regardless of position, rotation or scale of the parent plane object.

[image: Example]

Comment: i dont want extra objects as question stated